# How to show/hide fragment on button click

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have 2 `Fragments` - `ButtonFragment` and `ListViewFragment` - in my `Activity` `MainActivity`.

`ButtonFragment` contains a `Button`, `ListViewFragment` contains a `ListView`.

Each time I click on the `ButtonFragment` `Button` I want the `ListViewFragment` to show/hide.

How do I code this properly?

Currently my code looks like this:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Communicator {

    ButtonFragment buttonFrag;
    ListViewFragment listviewFrag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonFrag= new ButtonFragment();
        listviewFrag = new ListViewFragment();

        manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.button_fragment, buttonFrag, "Fragment1");
        transaction.add(R.id.listview_fragment, listviewFrag, "Fragment2");
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

ButtonFragment.java

```
public class DynamicButtonsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_fragment_layout, container, false);
        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //?? hide listview fragment from here ??
    }

}
```

ListViewFragment.java

```
public class ListViewFragment1 extends Fragment {

    protected ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {       

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

}
```

So my question is where do I implement the showing/hiding of `ListViewFragment`? I feel like I should send data to the `MainActivity` through the `onClick` method of `ButtonFragment`. But I do not know how to do so.

Or do I only add code in the `MainActivity` since the `MainActivity` has access to all the `Fragments`?

I am having trouble becase the `Button` is in a `Fragment`, not part of the `MainActivity`. I haven't really seen cases like this...

Can someone please help?

Comment: You certainly make many questions and comments in one post. I want to make these points. You don't send data to a Fragment, you can use findViewById method (read on this). A Button UI can be inside a Fragment, mainly because UI objects are supposed to be in a Fragment. You'll have to get comfortable with the Android framework, as I try to. Have fun...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show/hide a Fragment directly. You may show/hide a UI object like Listview. If you like, you can show/hide Fragment *indirectly* by using the `FragmentTransaction`, and you can call its method add, remove or replace.
A link for sample code is [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions)

Answer (score 1):

Do this ..

```
android.app.Fragment fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_FRAGMENT_TAG");
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragment);
```

inside your click event!

One more thing when you add fragments like this..

```
    transaction.add(R.id.button_fragment, buttonFrag, "Fragment1");
    transaction.add(R.id.listview_fragment, listviewFrag, "Fragment2");
```

you're expected to provide the container id instead of the id of the fragment.

Example: For MainActivity container use R.id.containerMain

Comment: this code looks good. I will try this soon! Regarding my container id, how do I know what the id of the container is? [and what exactly is the container]

Comment: You can set an id to any container layout (eg: root layout in layout_main) in xml. The container id is actually the id of any ViewGroup (i.e. layout) where you want to add your fragment into. @user2456977

Answer (score 0):

If you in fragment want to do some MainActivity function , you can try

```
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //?? hide listview fragment from here ??
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).hidelistView();
            //hidelistView you should imp in your MainActivity 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have fragments within the same layout, you can use the following code:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/Demonstrationofhidingandshowingfragments.htm

If not, than you can use several possibilities...
You can use an Intent to send data to MainActivity.
You can have a singleton instance where you store pointer to your MainActivity.

You can also use Handler to send messages, but the ways discribed above are easier to implement and should be enough for you.